# GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false not working on heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I deployed my react app on heroku and chose github as deployment method. To hide the source code, I added **GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false** in a **.env** but it didn't work. In **package.json** also I tried adding
**"build": "set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" && react-scripts build"** but it didn't work. I also added it in Config Vars in the heroku project settings.
Please help!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using linux adding it to the package.json will do the trick:

```
"scripts": {
     ...
  "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"
},
```